# HTML page didn't get fully loaded even after using JavascriptInterface

Tags: android, angularjs, webview

I attempted to parse html and some portion of that dynamically generated by javascript. Using javascriptInterface with WebView worked fine on pages that used normal javascript. However, when I attempted to do same approach on pages that were controlled by angularJS, it didn't work -- data from angularJS didn't get populated. For instance,

```
<span class="s1">
   <span class="s2">
       <em class="ng-binding">{{ someVariable }}</em>
   </span>
</span>
```

Inside curly bracket, the variable should be resolved by angularJS and its value was visible when I inspect web app through web browser. But html I saw on while processing html in javascriptInterface was following:

```
 <span class="s1">
   <span class="s2">
       <em class="ng-binding"></em>
   </span>
</span>
```

What my guess is the page was not fully loaded even with JavascriptInterface. Is there any other way to get fully loaded page from webview?

Comment: What it has to do with Android?

Comment: Because onPageFinished or JavascriptInterface didn't work on angular app which is based on javascript?